# Generate random doubles between a specific range

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to construct a neural network from scratch and I'm having some trouble initializing my weights matrices. I want the weights connecting the different layers to be randomly centered around 0 (ie values ranging from -0.5 to 0.5). I've tried

```
weights = np.random.rand(input_size, output_size) #input_size = # neurons in input layer, output_size = # neurons in output layer
```

but I think that only generates doubles between 0 and 1.

Comment: you can subtract 0.5 from `weights` then.

Comment: your statement makes a 2d array. I'd think single input and output layer weights would each need a 1d array of weights?

Answer (score 2):

Just subtract 0.5 from it

```
weights = np.random.rand(input_size, output_size) - 0.5
```

Voila!

**edit:**
To generate numbers between any range (e.g. between 3 and 7), you can do it like this:

```
min = 3
max = 7
weights = np.random.rand(input_size, output_size) * (max - min) + min
```

or like this

```
weights = np.random.uniform(min, max, (input_size, output_size))
```

Comment: Wow can't believe I didn't think of this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html#numpy.random.rand), `np.random.rand` generates "random samples from a uniform distribution over `[0, 1)`". You just need to subtract 0.5 from the array:

```
weights = np.random.rand(input_size, output_size) - 0.5
```

You might also want to generate random samples with different distributions. Many distributions are already available: [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.random.uniform`:

```
>>> np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, (2, 5))
array([[-0.22340556, -0.23382758, -0.30258041,  0.37783351,  0.27951709],
       [ 0.03336927,  0.41955043,  0.17132952,  0.29960474,  0.04237655]])
```